# How to deserialize below JSON response in swift?

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, json-deserialization

I have a json response. I'm bit confused on how to deserialize it. I want to extract the Id and Name from the below json response and store them as key value pairs in a dictionary.

**JSON Response**

```
("[{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"User\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v1.0/objects/User/01234\"},\"Id\":\"01234\",\"Name\":\"User1\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"1\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"User\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v1.0/objects/User/01235\"},\"Id\":\"01235\",\"Name\":\"User2\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"2\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"User\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v1.0/objects/User/01236\"},\"Id\":\"01236\",\"Name\":\"User3\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"3\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"User\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v1.0/objects/User/01237\"},\"Id\":\"01237\",\"Name\":\"User4\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"4\"}]")
```

I want to extract the id and name values from above json response and store them in a dictionary like below

dict = [01234:"User1", 01235:"User2", 01236:"User3", 01237:"User4"]

Comment: What you show as received from the server is not JSON

Comment: @JAAulde then what it is?

Comment: I have no idea. Nothing I’ve seen before.

Comment: @JAAulde look at my updated question

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong, i suggest you to try to use something like postman to check out response data. If postman also will return something like this which you shared, then talk with the guy who wrote this service because it isnt json.

Comment: Post the actual **JSON** not the output from your Xcode console to get help from others.

Comment: from the string, looks like you are getting the Array in Response, After decoding Json string, you need to traverse the Array & have to add the values in a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The server's response seems like an array, so you could deserialize it to something like `[String]`.

Then you define a structure that corresponds to the json inside that array, something like this:

```
struct ResponseElement: Codable {
  struct attributes : Codable {
     let type, url: String
  }
  let Id, Name, RecordTypeId: String
}
```

After that you decode it using this: `JSONDecoder().decode([ResponseElement].self, ...`

Finally you go over every element in your JSON to fill the dictionary, which has the following type `[Int:String]`

I tested this on Playgrounds, the full code is:

```
import Foundation

let serverResponse: [String] = [
   "[{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"User\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v1.0/objects/User/01234\"},\"Id\":\"01234\",\"Name\":\"User1\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"1\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"User\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v1.0/objects/User/01235\"},\"Id\":\"01235\",\"Name\":\"User2\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"2\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"User\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v1.0/objects/User/01236\"},\"Id\":\"01236\",\"Name\":\"User3\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"3\"},{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"User\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v1.0/objects/User/01237\"},\"Id\":\"01237\",\"Name\":\"User4\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"4\"}]"
]

struct ResponseElement: Codable {
  struct attributes : Codable {
     let type, url: String
  }
  let Id, Name, RecordTypeId: String
}

var dict:[Int:String] = [:]

if let serverResponseAsData = serverResponse[0].data(using: .utf8),
  let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ResponseElement].self, from: serverResponseAsData) {
  response.forEach { element in
     if let idAsInt = Int(element.Id) {
        dict[idAsInt] = element.Name
     }
  }
}

print(dict)
```

And this prints:

> [1235: "User2", 1237: "User4", 1236: "User3", 1234: "User1"]